# Angular.JS $http API request

Tags: javascript, html, json, angularjs, api

I have kind of a strange problem. Was looking everywhere but cannot find any solution. It is my first time with angular.js and I'm trying to get content from an API into my Angular App.

The Success Message works but the (data) is empty. If I change the GET URL to the one from w3Schools http://www.w3schools.com/website/Customers_JSON.php it works. So I'm not sure if my request URL http://fingerzeig.ch/api/agenda/list is formatted properly neither do i know if i need to decode or encode the data. If i compare the two pages i noticed that the fingerzeig URL is a little bit different.

Any help would be appreciated.

Here is my code myapp.js:

```
var app = angular.module("MyApp", []);

app.controller("PostsCtrl", function($scope, $http) {
  $http.get('http://fingerzeig.ch/api/agenda/list').
    success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
     console.log("success!");
     console.log(data);
      $scope.posts = data;
    }).
    error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
      // log error
    });
});
```

And here the HTML:

```
<body ng-app="MyApp">
              <div ng-controller="PostsCtrl">
                <ul ng-repeat="post in posts">
                  <li>{{post.ID}}</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
</body>
```

And here the links:

http://www.w3schools.com/website/Customers_JSON.php => WORKING

http://fingerzeig.ch/api/agenda/list => NOT WORKING

Here are the fiddels:
One with my request url with i want to make work. One with the example url from w3 schools. Only the GET url's are changed.

Fiddle not working: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/elpeyotler/s6wttym8/)

The one who works [link](http://jsfiddle.net/elpeyotler/s6wttym8/1/)

Thank you very much!

Comment: Please provide us a jsfiddle environment for better debugging.

Comment: Both urls look fine to me. Have you looked in your console for problems?

Comment: I made two fiddels. One with my request url with i want to make work. One with the example url from w3 schools. Only the GET url's are changed. Fiddle not working: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/elpeyotler/s6wttym8/) The one who works [link](http://jsfiddle.net/elpeyotler/s6wttym8/1/)

Comment: Can you please post your fiddle in your question?

Comment: @KevinB I checked the console; success is logged. No errors. Only data is not showing up. You can see it in the fiddles. Check my last comment

Comment: @elpeyotl Well, I see errors in the console (as expected) http://i.imgur.com/bvSPuGY.png

Comment: @jack thanks. Saw this before. Thought this was a chrome problem as i am developing locally. Disabled some security in chrome and the error did not show up. Well fiddle isnt working either so this is the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is probably a cross-domain issue. Note that `http://www.w3schools.com/website/Customers_JSON.php` has the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` response header and `http://fingerzeig.ch/api/agenda/list` does not.

```
$ curl -I "http://www.w3schools.com/website/Customers_JSON.php"
```

If you're making a cross-domain request you have to deal with CORS.

Comment: this could point me to the right direction. I never heard about CORS and Acccess control Origin. Im quite new in getting changing date over API's. Thanks!

Comment: Is there a way i can access the data or should the admin of fingerzeig change this access control?

Comment: @elpeyotl Ideally they would do it (and explicitly whitelist hosts and not do "*"). That said, you could always proxy through your own server OR use something like http://www.corsproxy.com/ ...Although I would only use that last one for testing (and not production and nothing sensitive)

Comment: @jack is correct. corsproxy  is a good way to get started.  http://www.ivivelabs.com/blog/fix-cross-domain-ajax-request-angularjs-cors/. This article will help you.