# Manipulate Data with JSON using Angular JS for WordPress JSON API

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, api

I tested code in [this post](http://fdietz.github.io/recipes-with-angular-js/consuming-external-services/requesting-json-data-with-ajax.html) and modified a bit for my use. But I cannot get JSON object from API of my blog that I have generated using WordPress JSON plugin.

1. URL API from BLOG (NOT WORKING): http://teckstack.com/api/get_recent_posts
2. URL from W3C example (WORKING):  http://www.w3schools.com/website/Customers_JSON.php

I stuck when tried to manipulated JSON API from my blog (mentioned above) and the same code worked for the other url provided by w3c example?

Please provide your suggestion.

I am using below codes in *`.html` file and not in WordPress environment*.

==== **Angular JS Script** ====

```
(function() {
    var app = angular.module('tsApp', []);
    app.controller('TSController', function($scope, $http) {
        $scope.heading = [];
        $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: 'http://teckstack.com/api/get_recent_posts'
        }).success(function(data) {
            console.log("pass");
            $scope.heading = data; // response data 
        }).error(function(data) {
            console.log("failed");
        });
    });
})();
```

==== **HTML** ====

```
<html ng-app="tsApp">
<body ng-controller="TSController as tsCtrl">
        <article class="main-content" role="main">
            <section class="row">
                <div class="content">
                    <div class="name-list">
                        <h1>Dummy Title</h1>
                        <ul>{{ 1+1 }} (Testing AJS is working)
                            <li ng-repeat="title in heading" class="">
                                <h3>{{title.Name}}</h3>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </section>
        </article>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I am raising this question after checking for all solution online
https://stackoverflow.com/a/26898082/1841647 and
http://www.ivivelabs.com/blog/fix-cross-domain-ajax-request-angularjs-cors/
But nothing worked for me.

Creating JSFiddle for your convenience:
http://jsfiddle.net/236gdLnt/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a cross-domain issue. You can get the first url data by rquesting it with [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP). Angular [support](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) it with the `$http.jsonp` method:

```
$http.jsonp('http://teckstack.com/api/get_recent_posts?callback=JSON_CALLBACK')
   .success(function (data1) {
        console.log("BLOG pass");
        $scope.heading1 = data1; // response data 
    }).error(function (data1) {
        console.log("BLOG failed");
    });
```

Make sure you add the `callback=JSON_CALLBACK` parameter to your url.

Comment: I tried as you suggested but not working :(. Updating fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/236gdLnt/1/

Comment: you didn't switch to the `$http.jsonp` method. check this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8r17vcg7/

Comment: Oh! Silly mistake. That's working now. Great help. Can you tel me specific link which can guide step by step to manipulate WordPress JSON API with AngularJS for HTML project?

Comment: One important input - if there is a cross origin error then we can use `https://crossorigin.me/` as a prefix to API url. (i.e: `https://crossorigin.me/http://teckstack.com/api/get_recent_posts?callback=JSON_CALLBACK`